# python if statement always false

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am having issues with an if statement always returning false. I am writing my code in Canopy. I am almost positive it's my syntax, because I replaced "is 'graj mahal'" with "> 200", input a value of 300 and it returned "sounds great!". Here is the excerpt of my code in question:

```
answer = str(raw_input("What do you want for dinner?"))
if answer is "graj mahal":
    print ("Sounds great!")
else: 
    print ("Ewie")
print ("the end")
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `==` not `is` for string comparison.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that already, but I it worked this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason OP's code was not working was that he was checking for the identity of two equal strings, which, even if equal, are not considered the same object.

In some conditions, the interpreter may cache string values (this is called string "interning"), but not always, and only for short strings.

It's very important to properly differentiate the concepts of identity and equality in Python. Identical objects sit at the same address in memory. Equal objects are considered so by the return value of `__eq__`.

Answer (score -2):

In `if` statements, you have to use either

- `==` for "is equal to"
- `>=` for "is greater than or equal to"
- `<=` for "is less than or equal to"
- `!=` for "doesn't equal"
- `>` for "greater than", and
- `<` for "less than"

Comment: This answer is very misleading. You don't need to use any of the listed comparison operators in an `if` statement. And `is` is a comparison operator just like the others, though with semantics that make it not the right one to use in the questioner's situation.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks!